# JModelAdmin - save() method. What's the purpose of $table->newTags?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, mvc, jtable, jmodeladmin

Can someone explain me why in the `save` method of the `AdminModel` class, there is the creation of a new `$newTags` property on the `$table`?

How this new property is used? How is it handled later on by the `JTable`, especially by the store() method?

> /libraries/src/MVC/Model/AdminModel.php #line ~1146

```
public function save($data)
{
    $dispatcher = \JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
    $table      = $this->getTable();
    $context    = $this->option . '.' . $this->name;

    if (!empty($data['tags']) && $data['tags'][0] != '')
    {
        $table->newTags = $data['tags'];
    }
//....
}
```

I am asking because under certain conditions, using the my model's `save()` method, I end up with a database error saying that there is no field `newTags` in my table.

- Do I have to do something in my own model's save() method to deal with this `$newTags`?
- Or do I need to include anything else in my own table class?

Comment: do you use Joomla! tags for your table? Do you use the term "tags" in your table?

Comment: yes I do use Joomla! tags and I have "tags" in my table. Is this what is causing my issues?

Comment: I don't think so. For some reason, the field newTags is send to the database. This should not happen. From my point of view, it is used to fill the tags field. Recommend to check the implementation for tags in com_content. Do you start implementing that tag stuff? If so, you might have a look at those observers for tags.

Comment: I have already implemented it and in my item's edit form everything works. I save tags to t5eqt_contentitem_tag_map and I retrieve them fine. My problem is when I call my item model save function from the items list - e.g. changing/toggling state of the item. This somehow ends up with that extra $newTags on my table which produces that error. So that's why I ask what's the deal with this $newTags property that gets created at that point. I don't understand why it is needed, if my data contain already $tags and how it is treated later on. I don't have problem when saving on my item's form.

Comment: @SvenBluege My assumption is that at some point the $newTags should be merged with $Tags - but still no real clue on the case.

Comment: I can't help any further without coding this myself :) I guess you already know that page? https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension

Comment: @SvenBluege, thanks for all your comments. Certainly it's not easy to help with it - I personally spent a hours on debugging this - following joomla core code - so that's why I ended up with the main question about the purpose of the $newTags and its destiny later on in the case it has been created, as The table ends-up with a new property $newTags that does not belong in the actual fields list. So far, I didn't managed to find a clue of what happens with this new property. I might end-up asking in github/joomla for this...

Comment: is the model's "event_before_save" value getting set properly when that happens?